# Search for a sub-string in a cell and do a vlookup on that sub-string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of objects which are text strings, where some of the objects have country names embedded in the string. I want to be able to pull out the country names, which I've identified in another list, and match it to a region. Please see below:

[image: Example]

I have columns A, B in one list, and then I have column E in another list. I want to be able to fill in column F with the correct region, or #N/A if there is no country text in column E.

What should be my formula in column F?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$8)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$8,E2))),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using array formula. Enter the following formula in `Cell F2`, drag/copy down as required.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(TRUE,IF(FIND($A$2:$A$8,E2)>0,TRUE),0))
```

Being an array formula, commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Above formula is case sensitive e.g. it will not match `hungary` and `Hungary`. If your want formula to perform non-case sensitive matches then you can use `UPPER` function as:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(TRUE,IF(FIND(UPPER($A$2:$A$8),UPPER(E2))>0,TRUE),0))
```